# are there two non-zero functons $f, g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f\ast g=0$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis

are there two non-zero functions $f, g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f\ast g=0$ a.e?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90608/does-the-banach-algebra-l1-mathbbr-have-zero-divisors

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) that $\widehat{f*g}=\hat f \cdot \hat g$.

Comment: Together with the injectivity of the Fourier transform on $L^1$.

Comment: $\hat{f}\cdot \hat{g}=0$, we can not get $\hat{f}\equiv0$

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: You pick two Schwartz functions $f,g$ with the property $fg=0$. Their inverse Fourier transforms satisfy $\widehat{\check f*\check g}=fg=0$.

Comment: @Shine: You don't want $\hat f\equiv 0$.  Your question asks that it not be $0$.